# Enabling liteMode in Javascript googlemaps api

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, javafx, ng-map

We are using JavaFX' WebView to embed a webpage where we want to display map content using google map's [javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) and [ng-map](https://ngmap.github.io/).

```
NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) {
                map.setOptions({
                    maxZoom: 17,
                    streetViewControl: true,
                    // liteMode: true, // that would be cool :-)
                    streetViewControlOptions: {
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT },
                    keyboardShortcuts: false,
                    //... ommited for brevity
                });
            });
```

As WebView is not supporting WebGL **we need to find a way to enable [lite mode](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3031966)** (as it is possible when using the [android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite?hl=de#adding_a_lite_mode_map)). Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Comment: Configure google maps how? How are you using google maps? There are multiple ways to consume the google maps service.

Answer (score -1):

When I just load google maps in a JavaFX WebView via URL I automatically end up in the lite mode. Are you sure this does not happen for you too?

Comment: Yes I do. When trying via Javscript API (ending up in an IFrame) it does not switch to lite ...